# Webpack Config for Static Pug/HTML Pages

Tags: angularjs, webpack, pug-loader

I'm transitioning a site to use Webpack, and I need a little help with configuration. I have a few pages written in [Pug/Jade](http://pugjs.org) that are large and infrequently accessed (think Terms of Service or Privacy Policy). Most of my `.jade` files are Angular templates, so those are inlined in their components and it works well. These few files, however, I would like Webpack to compile into static HTML files served separately from the rest of the app. However, I *would* still like their file names to include a hash.

The basic idea I've come up with is like this:

In `routes.ts`:

```
$routeProvider.when('/_tos', templateUrl: require('./resources/terms-of-service.jade'))
```

In `webpack.config.js`'s list of loaders:

```
{
  test: /resources.*\.jade$/,
  loaders: ['file?name=[name].[hash].html', 'pug-html']
}
```

I've tried that with various combinations of [pug-loader](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader), [pug-html-loader](https://github.com/willyelm/pug-html-loader) (with and without the `?exports=false` option), [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader), [extract-loader](https://github.com/peerigon/extract-loader), [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin), and [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader), but everything I try has extra artifacts in the resulting `.html` file. E.g. it might start with `module.exports =`, or it might put `\"` everywhere in the file that should just have `"`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah! I finally figured it out. I fundamentally misunderstood the way the list of loader works. I assumed only the first loader in the array that matched was used, but no, all loaders that match are used. (Though I'm still fuzzy on the details.) Here is a working configuration, where `resources` is the path to my "resources" directory:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jade$/,
    include: [resources],
    loaders: ['file?name=[name].[hash].html', 'pug-html?exports=false']
  },
  {
    test: /\.jade$/,
    exclude: [resources],
    loaders: ['pug-html?doctype=html']
  }
]
```